# How can the app usage of a single category be greater than the total app usage of the day?

Tags: macos, screen-time

In the following screenshot from a Macbook Pro, you can see that the screen time of the whole day sums up to 6 hours and 36 minutes, but the screen time of a single category (in this case, the only category on that day) is greater:

[image]

How can that be? How is this data to be interpreted?

Running on macOS 13.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can that be?

This «bug» occurs when you have multiple applications from a particular category running in the foreground at the same time (i.e. Slide Over).

This also happens when two instances of the same app (e.g. 2 Safari windows) are opened in the foreground simultaneously.

**Note:** This also applies on iPad but not on iPhone since two instances of the same app or category could not be ran simultaneously there.

Comment: I could replicate the issue on both Mac and iPad. For obvious reasons, this wasn't possible to replicate on iPhone.

Comment: Ok, so the category time is not meaningful (since at any given point in time I am looking at a one window at most, even if I'm going back and forth between two), and only the total daily usage is meaningful, right?

Comment: @talz Yeah, mostly. Even by app usage can be faulty. i.e. Having 2 Safaris opened so time spent being calculated innacurately.